# I am printing array of prime numbers , my code output is 2 , it is not iterating

Tags: java

```
public class Number {
    public void prime(int n) {
        int[] arr = new int[n+1];
        int counter = 0;

        for( int k=0;k<arr.length;k++) {

            for (int i = 2; i <= arr.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) {

                      if (i % j == 0) {
                         counter = counter + 1;
                      }
                }

                if (counter == 1) {
                      arr[k]=i;
                      System.out.println(arr[k]);
                }                                                  
            }                   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number fib = new Number();
        fib.prime(7);
    }
}
```

This is my code to get the array of prime numbers, but the `for` loops are not getting iterating.
What's wrong in my code?

Comment: The out is 2 for the above code

Comment: I'm not sure you use need 3 nested loops, but anyway, you should reset `counter` back to 0 before the inner loop begins.

Comment: You try to find n times the first prime?

Comment: Can you clearly state what it is that you want your program to do. Are you wanting to print out the fibonacci primes? e.g fib.prime(7) should print out the first 7 fibonacci  numbers that are prime?

Comment: I want to prime an array of prime numbers . like arr[10]={2,3,5,11, ..}

Answer (score 1):

First i don't know why you are using an array for this printing the prime numbers.
the main mistake in your program  counter variable is not reset for each inner loop iteration that's why  you are getting output as 2

Comment: Instead of resetting `counter` after each iteration of the middle for-loop, you could also just declare it in the loop's scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split your program:

1. `boolean isPrime(int)` - check given number is prime or not
2. get first `n` prime numbers
3. print result

First and Second steps could be like this:

```
public static int[] getFirstPrimes(int n) {
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;

    while(i < arr.length) {
        if(isPrime(num))
            arr[i++] = num;
        num++;
    }

    return arr;
}

public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if (num < 2)
        return false;

    for (int i = 2, sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(num); i <= sqrt; i++)
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```